# How to hide missing columns in AmChart?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

here what I have: https://jsfiddle.net/xfy5szkc/, value for UK object has undefined value, but I don't want to show column in this case, is there a way to change configuration to do it? I understand that I can remove this row from data provider, but it is only simplified example of real problem, in real problem I have clustered bars and this object will contain other values, because of it I can't remove it from dataProvider. Here graph configuration from my example:

```
{
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits"
  }
```

Comment: So what is your target functionality? Say you have two graphs clustered for each category. On one category one of the column is missing (value is undefined). Do you expect that particular category to shrink so that it accommodates only one column instead of two?

Comment: yes, I am expecting at least make it depend on some flag in data provider which I can set, but hide all undefined categories also option.

Comment: Well, categories will always be of the same constant width, regardless how many columns are there actually displayed. You can eliminate some categories altogether by pre-processing data though. If you think that would work for you, I can try to help you on that.